# to output all elements of square matrix in a spiral

Tags: java

The task  is  following:

> a square matrix A of order M is  given. Starting with the element A0,0 and moving clockwise, you  should output all its elements in a spiral: the first row, the last column, the last row in reverse order, the first column in reverse order, the remaining elements of the second row and so on.

```
public class Pres10Task8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m =4;

        int [][] a=new int [m][m];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i =0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j =0;j<a[i].length;j++){
                a[i][j]=rand.nextInt(100);
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(int k=0;k<m/2+1;k++){
            for(int j = k; j<m+1-k;j++){
                System.out.println(a[k][j]);
            }
            int j =m+1-k;
            for(int i=k+1;i<m+1-k;i++){             
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
            }

            for(int j=m-k;j>k;j--){
                 j =k ;
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
            }
            for(int i =m-k;i>k+1;i-- ){
                 i =m+1-k;
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Would you be so kind to look through my code and  say what is wrong with it? How should  I rewrite my code in order to get the right output?

Comment: Could you explain what makes you think that your code is incorrect? Do you get error, exception, incorrect results?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why you use Random - how you will see that it fills in in a spiral way?
Why jagged array instead of 2-dimensional?
I posted a sample for initialization and for printing out any array in fine readable way.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use a variable in your loop already exist before your method :

```
int j = m + 1 - k;
//  ^--------------------------------------Already exist
for (int i = k + 1; i < m + 1 - k; i++) {
    System.out.println(a[i][j]);
}

for (int j = m - k; j > k; j--) {
//       ^---------You can't declare a variable already exist, 
                   //you can just use it or initialize it
```

So instead use this without `int j`:

```
 for (j = m - k; j > k; j--) {
```

**Second**

```
System.out.println(a[i][j]);
//                   ^-----The i is not exist so you have to 
                         //create it and inisialize it so you can use it
```

Comment: Thank you for  your  answer. I correctted these  mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for  your  answer. I correctted these  mistakes. But  still concerning  the  second  mistake. should  i initate it  as int i=0 or  maybe  something like  this for(int i =0;i<a.length;i++). In  both caese  it  shows java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Than i've  changed int m  to 10, to 100 and  it shows  the  same  mistake only  when i  write 1000 it shows  no mistake. But  still  I  think  something is  wrong  with  te  logic here

Comment: @Vit i don't know what you want to do, i only guide you to correct your mistake, the logic of your algorithm is another  question, check the answer of Sanket Makani maybe this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You have made many mistakes as YCF_L mentioned in the answer and also After solving few of them I was still getting other errors. You can solve this problem by a simple logic that `Divide Square Matrix` into `smaller squares` and then follow the same pattern to print each of the `squares`.

For Example,

Suppose I have a matrix of order 5 then we can have `3 squares` here for distinct dimensions.

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Here each number represents that to which square the `element` belongs.So all outer elements belongs to `first square` then the next layer's elements belongs to `second square` and so on.

Now you have made your problem easier by dividing it into smaller `sub-problems` which can be solved in same way. Now you need to make logic of print the elements of each of the `squares`.

So for this, Consider the most outer square.

```
1 1 1 1 1                                        1  2  3  4  5
1       1       Thier Printing Order             16          6
1       1       ================>                15          7
1       1                                        14          8
1 1 1 1 1                                        13 12 11 10 9
```

So notice that we `start` from the `first element` and move into the `same row` into the `right direction`.

Then move in `same column` into `down direction`.

Then again in the `same row` in `left direction`.

At last in the `same column` but in the `up direction`.

After printing the `outer square` move to the `inner square` and do the same for each of the `squares`.

Code for the same:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int m =4;

        int [][] a=new int [m][m];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i =0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j =0;j<a[i].length;j++){
                a[i][j]=rand.nextInt(100);
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        int squares=m/2;                               //Calculating total number of squares

        for(int i=0;i<squares;i++)
        {
            int low=i;                             //Set the dimension of the square
            int high=m-i-1; 

            for(int j=low;j<=high;j++)             //First Row --> (Right Direction)
                System.out.println(a[low][j]);
            for(int j=low+1;j<=high;j++)           //Last Column --> (Down Direction)
                System.out.println(a[j][high]);
            for(int j=high-1;j>=low;j--)           //Last Row --> (Left Direction)
                System.out.println(a[high][j]);
            for(int j=high-1;j>low;j--)            //First Column --> (Up Direction)
                System.out.println(a[j][low]); 
        }

        if(m%2==1)                                 //If Matrix is of odd order then print the middle element.
            System.out.println(a[mid][mid]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you use jagged array `[][]` instead of 2-dimensional `[,]` ???
May give a simple sample:

```
public void CountDiag(int size)
    {
        // initialize straight order
        int[,] ar2 = new int[size, size];
        int count = 0;
        // initialize spiral way
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int top = 0;
        int bot = ar2.GetLength(0)-1;
        int left = 0;
        int right = ar2.GetLength(1)-1;
        do
        {
            //topleft to right
            for (; y < right; y++)
            {
                ar2[x, y] = count + 1;
                count++;
            }
            ar2[x, y] = count + 1;                
            right--;
            //topright to bottom
            for (; x < bot; x++)
            {
                ar2[x, y] = count + 1;
                count++;
            }
            ar2[x, y] = count + 1;                
            top++;
            //botright to left
            for (; y > left; y--)
            {
                ar2[x, y] = count + 1;
                count++;
            }
            ar2[x, y] = count + 1;
            left++;
            //botleft to top
            for (; x > top; x--)
            {
                ar2[x, y] = count + 1;
                count++;
            }
            ar2[x, y] = count + 1;
            bot--;
        } while (count < ar2.Length-1);
```

}

AND you print it out like this:

```
public void PrintArray(int[,] array)
    {
        int n = (array.GetLength(0) * array.GetLength(1) - 1).ToString().Length + 1; // for padding

        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++) // 0 - length rows
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++) // 1  length columns
            {
                Console.Write(array[i, j].ToString().PadLeft(n, ' '));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```